# My draw isn't working?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a basic game and I was wondering why I kept getting an error when trying to draw my sprite? Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

My Code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
import random

class sprite:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image1)
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50
        self.image.fill(255, 255, 0)

    def background(self, surface):
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load(white.png)
        screen.blit(self.image2, (0,0))

    def draw(self, surface):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1250, 500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

sprite=sprite

while True:
    pygame.init()
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.event.pump
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.quit()

    sprite.draw(sprite)
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/camil/Desktop/Polar Bear/PB.py", line 43, in <module>
    sprite.draw(sprite)
TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'surface'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you need to actually instantiate the `sprite` class. The line `sprite=sprite` should be something like `my_sprite = sprite()`, and then `my_sprite.draw(sprite)` instead of `sprite.draw(sprite)`.

However, you have other problems in your code as well.

In the `draw` function, the `surface` argument is unnecessary. You should just do this instead:

```
def draw(self):
    screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

and then `my_sprite.draw()` rather than `my_sprite.draw(sprite)`.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
def draw(self, surface):
    surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

and `my_sprite.draw(screen)`, which would also make sense.